# What can I use in a React app as an equivalent of Angular's $http.get

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking to make an http request within a React app and am wondering what the best method would be. 
I know in Angular you can use `$http.get`, so something like:

```
$http.get('API').success(function(data) {...
```

But what can I use for the same purpose within a React App. Would something like Axios work?

Forgive my ignorance, total newbie here.

Comment: Yes, axios is a viable alternative; we use it at my company, and is also included in many of the React tutorials on egghead.io

Comment: There are a lot of technologies to choose from. I would suggest follow this page https://github.com/petehunt/react-howto And pick the one that suites you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

checkout `window.fetch`. It has a very nice API to work with. It is a fetch function is now provided in the global window scope.

if you want to support browser without `fetch` implemented. try a polyfill like this one from github https://github.com/github/fetch

here is a quick example

```
// url (required), options (optional)
fetch('/some/url', {
    method: 'get'
}).then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json()
    }
}).then(function(json) {
    console.log(json)
    // set your state, your props, your child context do whatever you want
    // with the json
    // this.setState({ data: json })
}).catch(function(err) {
    // Error :(
})
```

Here a great [tutorial](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch)

Here is the [spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JQuery` library's ajax methods or specific libraries like `Superagent`. For `Superagent` just install it with `npm`, for example `npm i superagent --save` and make http requests for example:

```
request
   .get('/search')
   .end(function(err, res){
       // function body
   });
```

[Here](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) is complete documentation for it.

Comment: Why pull in the whole of JQuery just to use an HTTP lib? Why not use Axios, which is *just* an HTTP lib